# Bootstrap 3 columns, vertical-align: bottom with img

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get 3 columns with Bootstrap, with images (differents heights) aligned to the bottom and centered.

I want this:

```
col-md-4    |    col-md-4    |    col-md-4    
            |                |
            |                |    ---------
 ---------  |                |    ---------
 ---------  |    ----------  |    ---------
 -- img --  |    -- img  --  |    -- img --
 ---------  |    ----------  |    ---------
```

I tried this, but but unsuccessful, (uncentered, and suspect behavior)...

```css
.vertical-align{
    position: relative;
}
 
.vertical-align img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 vertical-align">
    <img src="images/antoine.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 vertical-align">
    <img src="images/logo_code.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 vertical-align">
    <img src="images/logo_android.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me, thanks !

Comment: check your snippet , it doesn't display your image

Comment: Seems to work fine http://www.codeply.com/go/06zoQBntbu .. are you setting height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could set up a jsfiddle or a codepen, that would be greatly appreciated.

Otherwise, give this a try:

```
.vertical-align {
   min-height: 1000px; /*Add a height or minimum height to the containers*/
   position: relative;
}

.vertical-align img{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left:auto;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a JSfiddle with your complete solution - the images are aligned to the bottom and centered in their respective parents. https://jsfiddle.net/o4kk49kz/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine, I've forgot to set the height.

Comment: Hey Antoine, glad I could help.

Can you please mark this as the correct answer?

Cheers.